# Copy filelist into a folder and recreate the folder structure (GUI) Win7 64?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

How can I copy some files and their related folders and subfolders from a "list_of_files.txt" into another folder? I'm looking for a GUI solution which runs under Windows 7 (64 bit).

**Example content of the "list_of_files.txt":**

> E:\archives\2013\06\0test01.pdf
>   E:\archives\2013\06\ahete.pdf

**Example of result needed : (files from E:\ are copied into C:\ok\ ):**

> C:\ok\archives\2013\06\0test01.pdf
>   C:\ok\archives\2013\06\ahete.pdf

Comment: Why do you need a GUI solution specifically? This sounds like one of those things for which the command line is ideally suited, and likely to be more practical.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of command line tools. But I always had problems with them because I have to rename my huge amount of files and/or folders to remove accents, symbols or even spaces...I would like to keep my files/folder structure the same. So I assuming a GUI software would be already compatible. Thanks in advance. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- [TreeCopy](http://download.cnet.com/TreeCopy/3000-2248_4-77660.html).
  [image]
- [TeraCopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy).
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but with TeraCopy I didn't find a way to copy the content of my "list_of_files.txt"(I have many many rows)! Thanks anyway. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have **List.txt** containing a list of complete paths to files (ensure any paths with spaces are double quoted), the following command run inside your target directory (in your case `C:\ok`) should do what you want:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in (List.txt) do md ".%~pa" & xcopy "%~a" ".%~pa"
```

Comment: This fails to answer the question as asked because the OP explicitly wants a GUI solution (now why that requirement, is beyond me).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please see my answer above. Thanks. ;)

Comment: @David: I don't quite understand what problems you've had using command line tools in the past. Anyway if you don't find a GUI program you can test the command above and see if it does what you need.

Comment: @Karan: Thanks. ;) I have tried your solution and the files are copied in "C:\user\david\" instead of "C:\ok".
Also accents are not copied. And what if I would like to move the files instead of copying them ? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: As per my answer you had to run the command from the *target* (i.e. `C:\ok`), not *source* directory. Copy List.txt also to the target directory beforehand. I will test with filenames that contain accents and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, regarding the accents, *if* you can save your filenames in a text file using *ANSI* encoding with no data loss, then specifying `chcp 1252` before giving the command above will ensure that accents are preserved while copying.

Answer (score -2):

this should work this should work trythis:

install, right click tray icon, click enter copy parameters, click import text file, input destination, click ok

http://www.copyhandler.com/

Comment: If you are going to provide a software recommendation it is customary to give a quick summary of the software and why you think it will fix the problem.